# Inserting a margin between h2 and span

Tags: html, css

I have a `<h2 class="landing-panel-title>` with a `<span class="landing-panel-icon-right ion-ios-search-strong>` nested inside. The second class on the span comes from a custom icons font called ionicons and is probably not relevant.

This is a header accompanied by an icon. I want to put a margin between the icon and the title (I want the icon on the far right when after text, and the text on the far right when the icon is on the left of the text), that auto expands as much as it can. I tried achieving this with `text-align`, but so far haven't been able to get it to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/eakfsLr3/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="landing-panel">
    <h2 class="landing-panel-title">Site Reviews<span class="landing-panel-icon-right ion-ios-search-strong"></span></h2>    
    <p class="landing-panel-text">I have been searching for different PTC sites, collecting knowledge and data, testing the theories, and made a general collection of what I found useful and relevant.</p>
</div>
<div class="landing-panel">
    <h2 class="landing-panel-title"><span class="landing-panel-icon-left ion-erlenmeyer-flask"></span>Methodical Approach</h2>
    <p class="landing-panel-text">We have collected data and tested the relevant info through my partner in crime, and he's using our guides and the knowledge to build his career in PTCs.</p>
</div>
<div class="landing-panel">
    <h2 class="landing-panel-title">Results<span class="landing-panel-icon-right ion-clipboard"></span></h2>
    <p class="landing-panel-text">We won't serve you bullshit, we give you relevant information that our staff has deemed legit and working. Enjoy the read!</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.landing-panel {
    background-color: #d5f5e3;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.landing-panel-title {
    width: 100%;
}
.landing-panel-icon-right, .landing-panel-icon-left {
    color: #913D88;
    font-size: 3em;
}
.landing-panel-icon-right {
    text-align: right;
}
.landing-panel-icon-left {
    text-align: left;
}
.landing-panel-title, .landing-panel-icon, .landing-panel-text {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `float:right`?

Comment: Could you attach an image of the effect of which you want to achieve?

Comment: I don't see in your source how the span gets its icon. With `::before` or `::after`, `background-image`, injected `<img>` element? The answer most likely will depend on the technique used.

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know, but here's the documentation. You'll probably find the anwser faster than I can [click](https://github.com/driftyco/ionicons)

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič it's OK, but could you explain what do you want in details?

Comment: I want the icons to the far right of the heading tag when they are right from the text, or when they are before the text, for the text to go to the far left. Guess I'll edit that into the main question for clarification

Comment: are you using the ionic framework, or just plain html/css with ionicons library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want this? http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/yv2xazjh/1/

```css
.landing-panel {
    background-color: #d5f5e3;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.landing-panel-title {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
.landing-panel-icon {
    display: table-cell;
    color: #913D88;
    font-size: 3em;
}
.landing-panel-title, .landing-panel-icon, .landing-panel-text {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.landing-panel-icon + .landing-panel-title {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="landing-panel">
    <h2 class="landing-panel-title">Site Reviews</h2>
    <span class="landing-panel-icon ion-ios-search-strong">Icon</span>
    <p class="landing-panel-text">I have been searching for different PTC sites, collecting knowledge and data, testing the theories, and made a general collection of what I found useful and relevant.</p>
</div>
<div class="landing-panel">
    <span class="landing-panel-icon ion-erlenmeyer-flask">Icon</span>
    <h2 class="landing-panel-title">Methodical Approach</h2>
    <p class="landing-panel-text">We have collected data and tested the relevant info through my partner in crime, and he's using our guides and the knowledge to build his career in PTCs.</p>
</div>
<div class="landing-panel">
    <h2 class="landing-panel-title">Results</h2>
    <span class="landing-panel-icon ion-clipboard">Icon</span>
    <p class="landing-panel-text">We won't serve you bullshit, we give you relevant information that our staff has deemed legit and working. Enjoy the read!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.landing-panel-title>span{
width:..px /*set as much required */
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;/* left/right */
}
```

or if You just want a small margin between them, then put `&nbsp;` before `span` element

or if you just want icon to be on the right of the header then-

```
.landing-panel-title>span{
position:absolute;
right:0;
/* This would make icon always at right */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your span class as **display:inline-block**

```
    span {
    display:inline-block; /*this enables margins to work*/
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```